# Keep android application open

Tags: android, multitasking

On the Android Market there is an app called Sleep Timer, and it is a type of alarm clock that brings runs the alarm even though you locked your phone while on facebook.  I made a type of app that detects movement however it only works if the phone is left on that app... How can I make it work when the app wasn't left upfront, but is still running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Android Services, which provide the functionality you seek. Basically they enable you to create components that run in the background even when the user switch away from your application.

You can find a very good introduction to them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html